# Export custom normals

Tags: export, import, normals

I am writing an importer and exporter for a custom binary format.
In this format I have triangulated mesh. Each vertex has position, normal, and UV.

The importer code sets them like this and it is displayed properly:

```
mesh = MyMesh(file_name)
bl_mesh = bpy.data.meshes.new(object_name)
bl_mesh.from_pydata(mesh.positions, [], mesh.indices)
bl_mesh.create_normals_split()
for l in bl_mesh.loops:
    l.normal[:] = mesh.normals[l.vertex_index]

bl_mesh.normals_split_custom_set_from_vertices(mesh.normals)
bl_mesh.use_auto_smooth = True
```

But the exporter code does not give me the same results.

```
mesh = MyMesh()
bl_mesh.calc_normals_split()
for l in bl_mesh.loops:
    mesh.indices.append(l.vertex_index)
    mesh.normals.insert(l.vertex_index, (*l.normal[:]))
```

[image]

I have tried accessing the `obj.data.vertices[].normal` but the normals there are wrong as well.

How do I get custom normals from the mesh?

UPD.
The full source code of the extension is in this [repo](https://github.com/Teivaz/PNUnpacker/tree/master/io_nebula). The model used is [nvx/model.nvx](https://github.com/Teivaz/PNUnpacker/blob/master/nvx/model.nvx) from the repo. All interactions with blender objects happen in the [io_nebula/bl_nvx.py](https://github.com/Teivaz/PNUnpacker/blob/master/io_nebula/bl_nvx.py)

Comment: Could give a running version of your script with example file, so we can test it ourselves? It is kind of hard to pinpoint the bug with just snippets

Comment: @WhatAMesh the extension can be found in this repo https://github.com/Teivaz/PNUnpacker and the mentioned mesh file you can find in the “nvx/model.nvx” in the repo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After hours of debugging I found out that list.insert function does not do what I expected (I was not alone in this assumption https://stackoverflow.com/q/25840177/3344612). And the order of vertices was messed because I inserted at a wrong index.

Answering my question. To get custom normals first call `calc_normals_split()` on the mesh and then access through `loops[].normal` with corresponding vertex indices in `loops[].vertex_index`.

To fix the mentioned code first resize the list and then modify with `[]` operator.

```
mesh.normals = [None] * len(bl_mesh.vertices)
for l in bl_mesh.loops:
    mesh.indices.append(l.vertex_index)
    mesh.normals[l.vertex_index] = l.normal[:]
```

Comment: When this works, it works great. But in some not very clean meshes you can end up with "None" elements in your normals[] array.

Comment: This is answer is not entirely correct. The number of MeshLoop's in a Blender mesh does not equal to the number of vertices. Loop is a face corner, so each face has at least 3 or more of the loops. Multiple loops can point to the same vertex. In this case, this algorithm only extracts the normal data partially.

So, in order to extract the data correctly, you need to calculate the average normal. And even in that case, the custom normal data will only be approximated.